# SharePoint Organization Chart is showing disabled user

Tags: 2013, user-profile

SharePoint Org chart is showing disabled user in AD. I already ran full sync but still it is showing. Management has now escalated this.

Note: We have disabled My site cleanup job.

So is there any way to remove them from org chart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the user still have a User Profile? Are you using AD Import or User Profile Synchronization Service (FIM)?

Comment: Yes,User still have user profile but it is under "Missing from import". I am using User profile synchronization.

Comment: This is because the disabled user profiles are not deleted. Hence, you need to create a separate managed-property maybe with the name of status and mark it as disabled. You can use this property to filter out the disabled users.